# Custom gRPC command for Dropwizard exits immediately

Tags: java, dropwizard

I've created an application using Dropwizard that starts a gRPC server. I do not use the regular server, and want to start my application using `java -jar my-fat.jar grpc config.yml` instead.

I've come as far as to add the command as the only available command during startup by overriding the corresponding method in the application class:

```java
public class App extends Application<Configuration> {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new App().run(args);
    }

    @Override
    protected void addDefaultCommands(final Bootstrap<Configuration> bootstrap) {
        bootstrap.addCommand(new GrpcCommand(this));
    }
}
```

I can launch my application using `java -jar my-fat.jar grpc config.yml`. My command looks like this:

```java
public class GrpcCommand extends EnvironmentCommand<Configuration> {

    public GrpcCommand(Application<Configuration> application) {
        this(application, "grpc", "Runs the Dropwizard application as a gRPC server");
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new environment command.
     *
     * @param application the application providing this command
     * @param name        the name of the command, used for command line invocation
     * @param description a description of the command's purpose
     */
    protected GrpcCommand(final Application<Configuration> application, final String name, final String description) {
        super(application, name, description);
    }

    @Override
    protected void run(final Environment environment, final Namespace namespace, final Configuration configuration) throws Exception {
        final var certificateService = AzureCertificateService.createWithClients(
                AzureSecretClient.create(configuration.getKeyVaultConfiguration()),
                AzureCertificateClient.create(configuration.getKeyVaultConfiguration())
        );

        final var validationService = CertificateValidationService.create(certificateService);
        final var signingService = CertificateSigningService.create(certificateService);

        final Pair<X509Certificate, KeyPair> certificate = certificateService.getSigningCertificateWithKeyPair();

        final BaseApiImpl baseApi = new BaseApiImpl(validationService, signingService);
        final GrpcServer grpcServer = GrpcServer.newBuilder()
                .withBaseApi(baseApi)
                .withConfiguration(configuration.getGrpcConfiguration())
                .withCertificate(certificate.getLeft())
                .withPrivateKey(certificate.getRight().getPrivate())
                .build();

        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                grpcServer.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).run();

        environment.healthChecks().register("grpc-server", new GrpcServerHealthCheck(grpcServer));
    }
}
```

The way that thread is started is not for production use, I'm just trying to get forward. The start method for the `GrpcServer` class:

```java
@Override
public void start() throws Exception {
    final NettyServerBuilder nettyServerBuilder = NettyServerBuilder.forPort(configuration.getPort())
            .addService(baseApi)
            .intercept(new OriginInterceptor());

    if (certificate != null && privateKey != null) {
        LOG.info("Got certificate and private key, enabling SSL");
        nettyServerBuilder.sslContext(buildSslContext());
    }

    server = nettyServerBuilder
            .build()
            .start();

    LOG.info("Server started at port {}", server.getPort());
}
```

And I see the message `GrpcServer: Server started at port 50441` in my log when I start. However, the application does not stay open. What am I missing? Shouldn't my use of the thread create a thread that stops the application from exiting? How can I keep the application running after the gRPC server has started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I disabled the server command, Jetty isn't started either (of course), which kept the application alive previously.

I found the simplest solution in the [gRPC Hello World Example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/HelloWorldServer.java).

My start method now looks like this:

```java
public void start() throws Exception {
    // Everything else as above

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(GrpcServer.this::stop));
    LOG.info("Server started at port {}", server.getPort());
    blockUntilShutdown();
}

private void blockUntilShutdown() throws InterruptedException {
    if (server != null) {
        server.awaitTermination();
    }
}
```